# Pause the Subscriber

Tags: .net, rebus

I have a requirement to be able to turn off/turn on subscribers.  The idea being that messages can be sent but if a subscriber is turned off, they just don't process messages in their queue.  Once turned back on, they begin processing messages in their queue.

I have looked at the pub/sub and request/reply examples, as well as pulled the source code for Rebus to look for any functionality that would answer this question.  There is a Defer method where a delay in time can be applied to sending the message, but the delay I need is based upon turning a subscriber on and off.

Main question, is there some way of pausing a subscriber?

(just one subscriber, not all subscribers, so I don't believe the SetWorkerThreads(0) technique would work)

**UPDATE** The answer IS using `_activator.Bus.Advanced.Workers.SetNumberOfWorkers(0)` like so:

```
public static class Subscriber1
{
    private static BuiltinHandlerActivator _activator;
    public static void Start(ILogger logger)
    {
        _activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator();
        _activator.Register(() => new Subscriber1MessageHandler());
        Configure.With(_activator)
                 .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq("subscriber1"))
                 .Logging(l => l.Serilog(logger))
                 .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map<Subscriber1Message>("thepublisher"))
                 .Start();
        _activator.Bus.Subscribe<Subscriber1Message>().Wait();
    }
    public static void Pause()
    {
        _activator.Bus.Advanced.Workers.SetNumberOfWorkers(0);
    }
    public static void Resume()
    {
        _activator.Bus.Advanced.Workers.SetNumberOfWorkers(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your subscriber deployed? Is it a Windows Service?

Comment: It's in a web api app in IIS, both publisher and subscribers are running in the same IIS process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you say

> just one subscriber, not all subscribers, so I don't believe the SetWorkerThreads(0) technique would work

because that would be my suggestion: To simply turn down the number of active worker threads to zero for that particular subscriber.

This way, it would stop receiving messages from its queue, and then message processing could be resumed by setting the number of workers back to some number greater than zero.

Btw. the syntax is like this:

```
bus.Advanced.Workers.SetNumberOfWorkers(0);
```

and it blocks until the number of workers has been adjusted.

Comment: I had it in my mind that SetNumberOfWorkers(0) meant that no subscribers would be working.  The pattern I used for testing was that every Subscriber exposes Pause and Resume like this: comment too long, updating post.